# can't get distance from raycaster

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on some code that allows me to move an object, that object contains the camera, so that it is like you can drive the object around the scene.

I am trying to use raycaster to measure the distance from the movable object to other objects that may be under the movable object.

would like to be able to use the distance to add to current movable object height.

this is a sample of the code I have come up with.

```
var origin = new THREE.Vector3(object.position.x,object.position.y,object.position.z);
//origin.normalize();
var direc = new THREE.Vector3(object.position.x,0,object.position.z);
direc.normalize();
alert('oX ' + origin.x + ', oY ' + origin.y + ', oZ ' + origin.z + ', dX ' + direc.x + ', dY ' + direc.y + ', dZ ' + direc.z);
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.set(origin,direc);
var intersected = raycaster.intersectObjects(self.scene.children);
for ( var intersect in intersected ) {
    alert(intersect.distance);
}
```

Using alerts the problem seems to be when I `direc.normalize()`.
This changes the x,y,z from what they should be.
Don't seem to give any results if I don't use `normalize()`.

The movable object is set to `matrixAutoUpdate = true;`

Answer (score 0):

The Vector class of has a [distanceTo](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3) function that might be of some you to you. It computes the distance of a vector to another vector.

```
var distance = mesh.position.distanceTo(intersected.object.position)
```

Comment: not sure if that will help. say my movable object is at x=5,y=.35,z=255. when I give these values to direc(would be x=5,y=0,z=255) it will not come back with any intersects. so I tried to normalize as it says in the documentation and my values get changed. I can get the distance in the above code, it is just not the right distance, the distance should end up being .35, but i get multiple intersects(should only be one if works correct) with distances of 69.023,309.54,369.2

Comment: Yeah, I dont really understand what you are trying to do

Comment: i have a cube that hold the camera. I can use the arrow keys on my keyboard to move the cube so that it would appear the cube is driving or flying or is a ship in the water( need to know the distance of object below my cube as it moves about.

Comment: So your "cube" is like a First person controller right? In order to get the distance of an object (below, above, infront, behind) use the toDistance function. Which would be `cube.position.distanceTo(intersected.position)`.

Comment: ok I will try that and see if I can get what I need that way. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, no prob. If you can create a http://codepen.io/ then i could take a look at the code.

Comment: seem to be having problem with getting the intersect.

Comment: sorry haven't got he codepen.io yet. please do not give up on me, I have recently had surgery, and have not been able to do it but will.